# Is it possible, in iOS / HTML5, to listen to a click event on an item over a <video> element?

Tags: ios, html, video

It seems to me that for some reason, you are not able to listen to click events on an element that you put over  element. If - for example - you would like to create your own "confirm" dialog boxes with two buttons, to be displayed over the  element, the buttons are not clickable.

The funny thing is that if the video is inside an iframe (as a YouTube embed) the buttons are working perfectly as expected.

Of course I'm talking about a video that is not yet started, when only the poster is displayed within the play button.

The video is 100%, not inline.

I'm not asking how to do add a button or a link centered on the screen, over a  element. I'm asking if someone else hit the same problem and found a suitable solution.

Listening for "touchend" instead of "click" does not help.

Comment: Because it's simple and easy to find. You just absolute position an element over your video element and use js to respond to the click event

Comment: MrJD, yeah of course. Read carefully.

Comment: Checked the z-indexing? Or if the clicks are hit at all and by which element?

Comment: No hit, nowhere. The only click received is by the "Play" button underneath my element :)